# Can't upgrade to newer versions of Gradle in Android Studio, nor update AS itself

Tags: gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm working with Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.14.
I wanted to update the Gradle distribution and the Gradle plugin in my project, so I started manually changing the lines:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+'` (in build.gradle)
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip` (in gradle-wrapper.properties)

by upgrading to, respectively, 1.0.0 and 2.2.1. Then I tried to use different combinations found here on SO, e.g. 0.14.4 and 2.2, as none of these seemed to work. For each combination I got (after syncing and downloading what needed) some error, like:

```
AssertionError: null

AssertionError: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectComponent@71c8dfe3

UnsupportedMethodException
Unsupported method: SourceProvider.getJniDirectories().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
```

After some research I thought this might be related to AS itself. Looking for updates in different channels brings me either to AS 0.9.9

> This patch will allow you to update from 0.x to 1.x. After updating,
>   please check for updates again to install 1.x.

or to AS 1.0.2.
When trying to update, I get hundreds of errors related to Android Studio not deleting some files in android_SDK_folder/sources/android-21 , mainly.

This issue has some references here on SO. Known fixes are killing java processes during the update, which was unsuccessful for me, and launching Android Studio as admin, which doesn't look like a great idea to me (and I wouldn't know how to on OS X).

I'm stuck. My questions are:

- are the Gradle syncing errors due to my old build of Android Studio?
- if so, what can I do to update? I don't think I should uninstall and then get 1.0.2, as the message I reported says I can patch to 0.9.9 and then to 1.x. Is this the only thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your Gradle syncing errors are due to a mismatch between the plugin and the version of Android Studio. If you want to use v1.0.0 of the plugin, you need to be running Android Studio 1.0 or later.

As for upgrading, my advice would be to do a clean reinstall of 1.0; it will be easier than trying to spend a lot of time figuring out why the upgrade isn't working. I forget where the SDK is installed in 0.8.14, but we're encouraging/requiring users to have the SDK located outside the application directory itself, so it should help avoid future SDK woes with upgrading/reinstalling Android Studio itself.

If the SDK is currently installed inside Android Studio's directory and you don't want to re-download it, you could move it out to a more sensible place before reinstalling, and point the new installation at it.

Comment: This solved. Android Studio could not deal with the SDK during the upgrade because it was located into the Android Studio directory. Moving the SDK outside resulted in a smooth upgrade to 0.9.9 and then to 1.0.2. Thanks.